# Multi-level sum in mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, laravel-4

I am working on mongoDB with Laravel using [jenssegers](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb). And i am trying to sum based on time.estimated_time_in_number.

I have MongoDB document which contains following data.

```
"time": [
     {
       "id": "QZMV154213",
       "estimated_time_in_number": 4.41
    },
    {
       "id": "QZMV154213",
       "estimated_time_in_number": 2.25
    },{
       "id": "QZMV154213",
       "estimated_time_in_number": 5
    }
  ]
```

I am using following query and it gives me 0 rather then 11.66.

```
Task::sum('time.estimated_time_in_number');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** to get the sum and the aggregation pipeline that gives you that result would be something like this:

```
db.task.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$time"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "total_estimated_time": {
                "$sum": "$time.estimated_time_in_number"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

which would give you the output

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "total_estimated_time" : 11.66
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

To implement this in laravel, use the raw query as follows which uses the underlying MongoDB aggregation framework above and is much faster, as well as generally more efficient than you will get out of the native framework interface:

```
Task::raw(function($collection){
               return $collection->aggregate(array(
                   array('$unwind' => '$time'),                   
                   array('$group' => array(
                       "_id" => 0,
                       "total_estimated_time" => array('$sum' => '$time.estimated_time_in_number')
                   )),
               ));
            });
```

---

-- **UPDATE** --

You could assign a variable the result from the MongoDB aggregation query as follows:

```
$result = DB::collection('tasks')->raw(function($collection)
{
    return $collection->aggregate(array(
           array('$unwind' => '$time'),                   
           array('$group' => array(
               "_id" => 0,
               "total_estimated_time" => array('$sum' => '$time.estimated_time_in_number')
           )),
      ));
 });
```

Comment: I have no idea about how to write raw query of mongoDB, So can you tell me how to add where condition in above raw query.

Comment: @GaurangGhinaiya The implementation is right there in the answer, assign the statement to a variable.